# First Kepler workspace is giving "Path must include project and resource name: /" for Maven project from SVN

Tags: eclipse, maven, eclipse-kepler

I've been using Indigo reasonably successfully for quite a while. Today I installed the STS for Kepler. I exported/imported my preferences and a Team Project Set for my (many) projects checked out from SVN.

I've noticed that when I switch to editor buffers for a particular Maven project, I get the following error often repeated multiple times:

"Path must include project and resource name: /"

This project was just checked out from SVN, and I was working on the same project in the Indigo workspace, and I wasn't seeing this error.

I've carefully examined everything in the Build Path tab, and I've manually examined both the .classpath and .project files.

The only thing that seems vaguely suspicious is the following block in my .project file:

```
        <buildCommand>
        <name>org.eclipse.ui.externaltools.ExternalToolBuilder</name>
        <triggers>full,incremental,</triggers>
        <arguments>
            <dictionary>
                <key>LaunchConfigHandle</key>
                <value>&lt;project&gt;/.externalToolBuilders/org.eclipse.wst.validation.validationbuilder.launch</value>
            </dictionary>
        </arguments>
    </buildCommand>
```

Comment: Do you have your .project file in the repository? And did you run a Maven "Update project configuration"?

Comment: Yes, the .project file is stored in SVN, and I did try "Update project configuration".  No effect.

Comment: Never store your `.project` and `.metadata` in your SVN. They contain information that might change for each developer/machine. Especially if you use Maven which builds the project config for you this is unnecessary. Of course this still doesn't solve your problem, which I sadly have no idea on.